# Mongoid: cannot embed different classes in one array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, inheritance, mongoid

I have Mongoid classes as follows:

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :animals
end

class Animal
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :order

  def self.has_gender
    field :gender, type: String
  end
end

class Deer < Animal
  has_gender
end
```

and when I call animals on any order, even empty one:

```
Order.new.animals
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `has_gender' for Deer:Class
```

Any ideas?

Comment: so far the only idea I have about that is that embedding different sub-classes of one class isn't supported in Mongoid. If so, anybody has some ideas how to solve this problem in another, but still elegant way?

Comment: Works for me: http://pastie.org/4228557

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks, so it looks like error is somewhere else (I didn't checked that simply classes case, I've just extracted stuff from my classes which I think are causing it), I will look for it

Comment: In console, when I just try to call "Deer", I'm getting error: LoadError: Expected /home/.../app/models/deer.rb to define Deer

Comment: Well, does that file define Deer?

Comment: yes, as above: class Deer < Animal; end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is somewhere else. Your code works on my machine. (I'm using Mongoid 3.0-rc, though).

```
order = Order.new
order.animals << Animal.new
order.animals << Deer.new
order.save

puts Order.first.animals
# >> #<Animal:0x007fca04bae890>
# >> #<Deer:0x007fca04bb4b50>
```

Comment: I think that the problem is in the way I create sub-classes:

    TYPES = {'deer' => Deer, 'pig' => Pig, 'duck' => Duck}

Comment: in Game class (i've posted answer with details on that)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in the way I create sub-classes:

```
class Game
  include Mongoid::Document
  TYPES = {'deer' => Deer, 'pig' => Pig, 'duck' => Duck}
  def self.new_of_type(type, attrs={})
    TYPES[type].new attrs
  end
```

end

because when I commented out line when I define TYPES, error disappeared, so the problem may be with calling subclasses when defining TYPES (Deer, Pig, Duck).

Any ideas for a better solution for creating sub-classes? i'm doing it this way in controller:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @game = Game.new_of_type params[:type], params[:game]
    @game.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I was calling sub-classes when defining TYPES constant within parent class - that is nonsense, as when I define parent class, sub-classes then aren't yet defined! :) Thanks Sergio for Your time!